# Python. После компиляции появляется ошибка связанная с pynput.keyboard (до компиляции таковой нет)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот сама ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "layout.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode, Key, Controller
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
ImportError
[11436] Failed to execute script
```

Пишу на Python 3.8.5. Что делать - не представляю.
Код:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import ctypes
import threading
import pyperclip
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode, Key, Controller

keyboard=Controller()
pressed_vks=set()

entoru={'~': 'Ё', 'Q': 'Й', 'W': 'Ц', 'E': 'У', 'R': 'К', 'T': 'Е', 'Y': 'Н', 'U': 'Г', 'I': 'Ш', 'O': 'Щ', 'P': 'З', '{': 'Х', '}': 'Ъ', 'A': 'Ф', 'S': 'Ы', 'D': 'В', 'F': 'А', 'G': 'П', 'H': 'Р', 'J': 'О', 'K': 'Л', 'L': 'Д', ':': 'Ж', '"': 'Э', 'Z': 'Я', 'X': 'Ч', 'C': 'С', 'V': 'М', 'B': 'И', 'N': 'Т', 'M': 'Ь', '<': 'Б', '>': 'Ю', '|': '/', '`': 'ё', 'q': 'й', 'w': 'ц', 'e': 'у', 'r': 'к', 't': 'е', 'y': 'н', 'u': 'г', 'i': 'ш', 'o': 'щ', 'p': 'з', '[': 'х', ']': 'ъ', 'a': 'ф', 's': 'ы', 'd': 'в', 'f': 'а', 'g': 'п', 'h': 'р', 'j': 'о', 'k': 'л', 'l': 'д', ';': 'ж', "'": 'э', 'z': 'я', 'x': 'ч', 'c': 'с', 'v': 'м', 'b': 'и', 'n': 'т', 'm': 'ь', ',': 'б', '.': 'ю', '?': ',', '/': '.', '@': '"', '#': '№', '$': ';', '&': '?', '^': ':'}
rutoen={'Ё': '~', 'Й': 'Q', 'Ц': 'W', 'У': 'E', 'К': 'R', 'Е': 'T', 'Н': 'Y', 'Г': 'U', 'Ш': 'I', 'Щ': 'O', 'З': 'P', 'Х': '{', 'Ъ': '}', 'Ф': 'A', 'Ы': 'S', 'В': 'D', 'А': 'F', 'П': 'G', 'Р': 'H', 'О': 'J', 'Л': 'K', 'Д': 'L', 'Ж': ':', 'Э': '"', 'Я': 'Z', 'Ч': 'X', 'С': 'C', 'М': 'V', 'И': 'B', 'Т': 'N', 'Ь': 'M', 'Б': '<', 'Ю': '>', '/': '|', 'ё': '`', 'й': 'q', 'ц': 'w', 'у': 'e', 'к': 'r', 'е': 't', 'н': 'y', 'г': 'u', 'ш': 'i', 'щ': 'o', 'з': 'p', 'х': '[', 'ъ': ']', 'ф': 'a', 'ы': 's', 'в': 'd', 'а': 'f', 'п': 'g', 'р': 'h', 'о': 'j', 'л': 'k', 'д': 'l', 'ж': ';', 'э': "'", 'я': 'z', 'ч': 'x', 'с': 'c', 'м': 'v', 'и': 'b', 'т': 'n', 'ь': 'm', 'б': ',', 'ю': '.', ',': '?', '.': '/', '"': '@', '№': '#', ';': '$', '?': '&', ':': '^'}
uptolow={'Ё': 'ё', 'Й': 'й', 'Ц': 'ц', 'У': 'у', 'К': 'к', 'Е': 'е', 'Н': 'н', 'Г': 'г', 'Ш': 'ш', 'Щ': 'щ', 'З': 'з', 'Х': 'х', 'Ъ': 'ъ', 'Ф': 'ф', 'Ы': 'ы', 'В': 'в', 'А': 'а', 'П': 'п', 'Р': 'р', 'О': 'о', 'Л': 'л', 'Д': 'д', 'Ж': 'ж', 'Э': 'э', 'Я': 'я', 'Ч': 'ч', 'С': 'с', 'М': 'м', 'И': 'и', 'Т': 'т', 'Ь': 'ь', 'Б': 'б', 'Ю': 'ю', 'Q': 'q', 'W': 'w', 'E': 'e', 'R': 'r', 'T': 't', 'Y': 'y', 'U': 'u', 'I': 'i', 'O': 'o', 'P': 'p', 'A': 'a', 'S': 's', 'D': 'd', 'F': 'f', 'G': 'g', 'H': 'h', 'J': 'j', 'K': 'k', 'L': 'l', 'Z': 'z', 'X': 'x', 'C': 'c', 'V': 'v', 'B': 'b', 'N': 'n', 'M': 'm'}
lowtoup={'ё': 'Ё', 'й': 'Й', 'ц': 'Ц', 'у': 'У', 'к': 'К', 'е': 'Е', 'н': 'Н', 'г': 'Г', 'ш': 'Ш', 'щ': 'Щ', 'з': 'З', 'х': 'Х', 'ъ': 'Ъ', 'ф': 'Ф', 'ы': 'Ы', 'в': 'В', 'а': 'А', 'п': 'П', 'р': 'Р', 'о': 'О', 'л': 'Л', 'д': 'Д', 'ж': 'Ж', 'э': 'Э', 'я': 'Я', 'ч': 'Ч', 'с': 'С', 'м': 'М', 'и': 'И', 'т': 'Т', 'ь': 'Ь', 'б': 'Б', 'ю': 'Ю', 'q': 'Q', 'w': 'W', 'e': 'E', 'r': 'R', 't': 'T', 'y': 'Y', 'u': 'U', 'i': 'I', 'o': 'O', 'p': 'P', 'a': 'A', 's': 'S', 'd': 'D', 'f': 'F', 'g': 'G', 'h': 'H', 'j': 'J', 'k': 'K', 'l': 'L', 'z': 'Z', 'x': 'X', 'c': 'C', 'v': 'V', 'b': 'B', 'n': 'N', 'm': 'M'}

EXITCOMBO=[
    {Key.shift, KeyCode(vk=192)}
]

SWITCHKEYCOMBO=[
    {Key.shift, Key.alt_l}
]

SWITCHRGSTRCOMBO=[
    {Key.caps_lock}
]

def on_press(key):
    global pressed_vks
    vk = get_vk(key)
    pressed_vks.add(vk)
    
    for combination in SWITCHKEYCOMBO:
        if is_combination_pressed(combination):
            SKthread=threading.Thread(target=SwitchKeysLanguage(),args=())
            SKthread.start()
            return False
            break
    for combination in SWITCHRGSTRCOMBO:
        if is_combination_pressed(combination):
            SRthread=threading.Thread(target=SwitchKeysRgstr(),args=())
            SRthread.start()
            return False
            break

def on_release(key):
    global pressed_vks
    vk=get_vk(key)
    pressed_vks=set()

def is_combination_pressed(combination):
    return all([get_vk(key) in pressed_vks for key in combination])

def get_vk(key):
    return key.vk if hasattr(key, 'vk') else key.value.vk

def Copy():
    global pressed_vks
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press(KeyCode(vk=67))
    keyboard.release(KeyCode(vk=67))
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
    pressed_vks=set()
    return pyperclip.paste()

def Paste(msg):
    global pressed_vks
    pyperclip.copy(msg)
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press(KeyCode(vk=86))
    keyboard.release(KeyCode(vk=86))
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
    pressed_vks=set()

def Language():
    user32=ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
    curr_window=user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    thread_id=user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(curr_window, 0)
    klid=user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
    lid=klid & (2**16-1)
    lhex=hex(lid)
    return lhex

def Rgstr():
    user32=ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
    rgstr=user32.GetKeyState(0x14)
    return rgstr

def SwitchKeysLanguage():
    global pressed_vks
    pressed_vks=set()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    language=Language()
    if language=='0x419': #Russian
        msg=Correcter(entoru,Copy())
    elif language=='0x409': #English
        msg=Correcter(rutoen,Copy())
    else:
        pass
    time.sleep(0.01)
    Paste(msg)
    listener=Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()

def SwitchKeysRgstr():
    global pressed_vks
    pressed_vks=set()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    rgstr=Rgstr()
    if rgstr==1: #UpperCase
        msg=Correcter(lowtoup,Copy())
    elif rgstr==0: #LowerCase
        msg=Correcter(uptolow,Copy())
    else:
        pass
    time.sleep(0.01)
    Paste(msg)
    listener=Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()

def Correcter(dict,msg):
    halfmsg=''
    for i in range(0,len(msg)):
        tempmsg=msg[0]
        try:
            tempmsg=tempmsg.replace(tempmsg[0],dict[tempmsg[0]],1)
        except:
            pass
        halfmsg=halfmsg+tempmsg
        msg=msg[1:]
    return halfmsg

def kill(key):
    vk = get_vk(key)
    pressed_vks.add(vk) 
    for combination in EXITCOMBO:
        if is_combination_pressed(combination):
            return False

def ListenerFunction():
    with Listener(on_press=kill, on_release=kill) as listener:
        listener.join()

def LifeCycle():
    ListenerThread=threading.Thread(target=ListenerFunction,args=())
    ListenerThread.start()
    sys.exit()

listener=Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

LifeCycle()
```

Comment: Когда вы уже поймёте что python это интерпретируемый язык программирования и перестанете его мучить... Идите С++ мучайте

Comment: @Inventor лол, спс, мне учитель по информатике посоветовал python (я то не шарю), сейчас почитал что такое интерпретируемый и компилируемый языки, согласен с тобой можно считать вопрос закрытым